# How do I remove all elements from a numpy array that are equal to zero in another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indices

How do I remove all elements from a numpy array that are equal to zero in another array?

I want to use the indices of one numpy array `mask` where `mask==0` to delete the elements of another same-shaped array `array`.

I tried something like `np.delete(array,mask==0)` but that just gave me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `np.where`

```
array = array[np.where(another_array != 0)]
```